# How to test existence of a file or symlink, even broken one, in Bash?

Tags: bash

In Bash, I want to say **"if `~/.gitconfig` exists, do something"** but have trouble coming up with the right condition. I need to account for plain files, valid symlinks and broken symlinks.

Things I tried that don't work:

- `if [[ -L "$HOME/.gitconfig" ]]` – returns false when `.gitconfig` is a plain file.
- `if [[ -e "$HOME/.gitconfig" ]]` – returns false when `.gitconfig` exists but is a broken symlink.

Is there a switch that can do what I want, or do I need to come up with a more complex condition?

**UPDATE**: I removed the mention of removing files, I'm only interested in the condition, not the action(s) that happen after that.

Comment: `if [[ -L "$HOME/.gitconfig" && ! -e "$HOME/.gitconfig" ]]; then echo "$HOME/.gitconfig" is a dangling symlink"; fi`

Comment: @chepner I removed the mentions of removing files, I actually need to do more complex stuff in the IF block, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

This condition does what I need (though I'd still prefer a single switch / test if it existed):

```sh
file="$HOME/.gitconfig"

if [[ -e $file || -L $file ]]; then
  echo "File exists"
fi
```

Comment: you should split and reverse the condition: `if test -L "$file" || test -e "$file"`.  `test` does not abort on first match but evaluates every condition.  And doing `lstat()` (the `-L`) before `stat()` might be more SELinux friendly...

Answer (score 0):

I normally use -s, because when manipulating a list of files, I send the list into a file, and repeatedly pull the first line out of the file with ed.  The -s switch is only true while the file length is non-zero, which means that the loop will stop once I've deleted every line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps readlink is what you're looking for?

```
$ readlink /tmp/link; echo $?
below cmd output started 2020 Fri Mar 27 08:00:38 AM PDT
/tmp/notthere
0
above cmd output done    2020 Fri Mar 27 08:00:38 AM PDT
dstromberg@dstromberg-inspiron-5570:~ x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 4291

$ readlink /etc/passwd; echo $?
below cmd output started 2020 Fri Mar 27 08:00:46 AM PDT
1
above cmd output done    2020 Fri Mar 27 08:00:46 AM PDT
dstromberg@dstromberg-inspiron-5570:~ x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 4291

$ readlink /tmp/nonexistent; echo $?
below cmd output started 2020 Fri Mar 27 08:00:56 AM PDT
1
```

HTH